# Ember data doesn't append parameters to the query

Tags: javascript, model, ember.js, ember-data, query-string

Ember data just doesn't append parameters to the query. I have a tags route like this

example

```
App.TagsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function(params) {
    var tag = params.tag_name;
    var entries = this.store.find('entry', {tags: tag});
    return entries;
 }
});
```

but this keeps making the same request as this.store.find('entry'). 
i'm doing it wrong?

**Edit:**

My router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
 this.resource('entries', function(){
  this.resource('entry', { path: '/entry/:entry_id/:entry_title' });
 });
 this.route('tags', { path: '/t/:tag_name' });
});
```

when i request (for example) localhost:8888/#/t/tag 
the value of params.tag_name is 'tag'

**edit2:**

My REST adapter

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    bulkCommit: false,
    buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
      var s = this._super(record, suffix);
      return s + ".json";
    },
    findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
      var url = this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 
      proc = 'GET', 
      obj = { data: query },
      theFinalQuery = url + "?" + $.param(query);
      console.log(url); // this is the base url
      console.log(proc); // this is the procedure
      console.log(obj); // an object sent down to attach to the ajax request
      console.log(theFinalQuery); // what the query looks like
      // use the default rest adapter implementation
      return this._super(store, type, query);
    }
 });
```

**edit3:**

making some changes to my TagsRoute object i get the next output:

```
App.TagsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function(params) {
    var tag = params.tag_name;
    var query = {tags: tag};
    console.log(query);
    var entries = this.store.find('entry', query);
    return entries;
 }
});
```

**console output when i request localhost:8888/#/t/tag**

Object {tags: "tag"} 
(host url) + api/v1/entries.json
GET
Object {data: Object}
 
(host url) + api/v1/entries.json?tags=tag
Class {type: function, query: Object, store: Class, isLoaded: true, meta: Object…}

Ember data is attaching GET parameters. i think my error maybe is the requested url, it should be something like this 
**(host url) + api/v1/tags/:tag_name.json**  
instead of
**(host url) + api/v1/entries.json?tags=:tag_name**

**SOLUTION**

the build of ember-data (ember-data 1.0.0-beta.3-16-g2205566) was broken. When i changed the script src to builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/canary/daily/20131018/ember-data.js everything worked perfectly. 
the proper way to add GET parameters is:

```
var query = {param: value};
var array = this.store.find('model', query);
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What's the request that's being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything correct, are you sure the request being sent back to the server doesn't contain the query?

The full query isn't created until JQuery makes the call.

Did you look at the network tab in chrome (or whatever browser you are using) to see what it's sending back.

Watch the console in the jsbin below, it shows what happens when you use find with an object (for querying):

```
App.MyAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
 findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
    var url = this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 
        proc = 'GET', 
        obj = { data: query },
        theFinalQuery = url + "?" + $.param(query);
    console.log(url); // this is the base url
    console.log(proc); // this is the procedure
    console.log(obj); // an object sent down to attach to the ajax request
    console.log(theFinalQuery); // what the query looks like
    // use the default rest adapter implementation
    return this._super(store, type, query);
  },
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AyaVakE/1/edit

Additional questions:

hitting: `http://localhost:8888/#/t/tag`  fires the tags route, sending in 'tag' to the tag_name.  Your model hook is correct.  Where are you seeing that the request is the same?

Additionally, you mentioned store.find('entries) and store.find('entry').  I know they handle pluralization of most things, but you should make sure those end up being the same endpoint /api/entries.

Comment: thanks for your answer @daniel ! 
entries and entry resources are pointing to api/entries. 
If i request (example) http://localhost:8888/#/t/tag the api filters the response with the param 'tag'.
in that case i have to point to api/tags/tag.json (with param = 'tag').
The network tab in chrome is showing me the same request as this.store.find('entry'). without GET parameters attached, thats the problem. (i'm seeing that request)

Comment: If you add and use the adapter I showed above, and use it instead, what does it output in the console?

Comment: What version of ember data are you using?

Comment: let me try with your adapter. I'm using ember 1.0.0 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.3-16-g2205566

Comment: i edited with the new rest adapter. the console doesnt output anything

Comment: Will you pull out the object in the find request (of your model hook), so it's like this, and console it out.
 var tag = params.tag_name;
    var query = { tags: tag };
    console.log(query);
    var entries = this.store.find('entry', query);

Comment: Did you save?  I don't see any change

Comment: So are you trying to get tags, or entries?

Comment: i'm trying to get entries tagged with tag_name parameter (i'm using the gem ActsAsTaggableOn for that)

Comment: on the server side the route 'api/v1/tags/:tag' is pointing to entries#index controller

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ruby, but it sounds like the issue is your backend doesn't match the endpoint that's an Ember Data standard.  Ember Data's standard is /type/id or /type?param=value

Comment: yep, look like it's a routing problem. i'll keep trying changing my backend. thanks @Daniel!

Comment: actually... i can do (and i'm doing): host + /api/v1/entries.json?tag=:tag_name to filter entries with tags, but chrome inspector in network section show me the request without ?tag=:tag_name (dont know why)

Comment: Have you tried debugging into the find method of the store and made sure it's going into the findQuery method?

Comment: i think it's going into findQuery because the console outputs the value of url, proc, obj and theFinalQuery

Comment: Hah, that's crazy, I guess that's part of the excitement with using beta builds.  I can't wait for a stable 1.0 of ED

Answer (score 0):

The `RESTAdapter` sends your query object to the `jQuery.ajax()` method by tacking it onto the `data` property of the settings object. (See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for info on what is done with the settings object.)

It looks like maybe the tag name is not defined. Try to make sure that the `tag_name` parameter is properly coming from your route.